# HTML wont link with CSS. they are both in the same folder

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title> navigation practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> ABOUT</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>camp sites</a></li>
                    <li><a>our team</a></li>
                    <li><a>wildlife</a></li>
                    <li><a>resources</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> CONTACT</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>email</a></li>
                    <li><a>phone</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">things to do</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>shops</a></li>
                    <li><a>activities</a></li>
                    <li><a>trails</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> MORE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS just has:

```
body {
  background: blue
}
```

both the HTML and CSS are in the same file. I’ve checked spelling on the link, syntax and any errors in the CSS. I’ve also tried opening the file in a different browser. I have this problem every time I start a new project. I’m using Notepad++.

Comment: I have the <!DOCTYPE html> and the opening and closing tags of <html></html> they just didn't show in the question

Comment: It’s `rel="stylesheet"` not `rel="stylesheets"`. Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/) before posting. The validator produces _“**Error**: Bad value `stylesheets` for attribute `rel` on element `link`: The string `stylesheets` is not a registered keyword.”_.

Comment: _“they just didn't show in the question”_ — Read [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212).

Comment: wow simple error, thank you so much

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept the answer. @Xufox why not add a answer so he can accept.

Comment: @AhmadBilal Because typo-related questions are off-topic and should be closed as such, not answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your stylesheet tag, you added a unnecessary "S" at the end of the word, it is supposed to be:

`<link rel="`**`stylesheet`**`" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>`

not **`stylesheets`**.

And you forgot to open the `html` tag after the `<!doctype html>` declaration, and the charset declaration. Here is how it is supposed to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> navigation practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--YOUR CODE HERE-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Try validating your code here: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html. It will show what's wrong on it.